# how to run youtube links with while loop in php from database?

Tags: php, html, iframe, youtube

I want to fetch YouTube embedded link from database and to run in a while loop that its not coming in while loop.

```
<?php
    $video_query=mysqli_query($connect,"select Vdo_SNo, Vdo_Name, Vdo_Category, Vdo_Discription, Vdo_Date from user_videoarena where user_did='3' AND Vdo_Category='Portfolio' ORDER BY Vdo_SNo DESC ");                    
    $i = 1;
    while ($video_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($video_query)){
?>
    <div class="video_sec fl">
    <?php echo $video_Row['Vdo_Name']; ?>                        
    </div><!------------ video_sec -------------------->                        
<?php $i++; }
?>
```

With this code only a single video is fetching but not all that is stored in database.

Comment: SELECT count(*) from user_videoarena where user_did=3 AND Vdo_Category='Portfolio' ......... run this query and check the count first.. check in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

try

```
           <?php
            $video_query=mysqli_query($connect,"select Vdo_SNo, Vdo_Name, Vdo_Category, Vdo_Discription, Vdo_Date from user_videoarena where user_did='3' AND Vdo_Category='Portfolio' ORDER BY Vdo_SNo DESC LIMIT 10 ");                    
            while($video_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($video_query)){
            ?>
                <div class="video_sec fl">
                <?php echo $video_Row['Vdo_Name']; ?>   
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: LIMIT 10 is the change you can change it to the maximum number of what you want to display  and delete  $i = 1; not need to increase it for no reason

Comment: There is no any change with this..... the problem is still same... Actually I have youtube links in my database and I want to show all youtube videoes      on my page through php while loop but it's showing only one video.

Comment: @RoshanKumar can you show me the output of 
$video_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($video_query);
print_r($video_Row);
without using while loop

Comment: <?php
                    $video_query=mysqli_query($connect,"select Vdo_SNo, Vdo_Name, Vdo_Category, Vdo_Discription, Vdo_Date from user_videoarena where user_did='3' AND Vdo_Category='Portfolio' ORDER BY Vdo_SNo DESC LIMIT 10 ");
     $video_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($video_query);      
     print_r($video_Row);
     ?>                 OUTPUT: Array ( [0] => 6 [Vdo_SNo] => 6 [1] =>

Comment: @Hisham Elsayad: Did you get any idea on this. I am still trying to solve this issue...

Comment: cant see full output

Answer (score 0):

If Your record is row-wise in Sql Table then You Have to use a Simple For-loop 
First store the result of query in one array.
Then print the array and check the output. If output is same as you want. and if not then you have something mistake in query.
Then simply make a loop like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array_name);$i++){
echo $array[$i]['field name_in_database'];
}
```

Hope this solution help you.